# Wait for setAttribute() method in order to execute another action

Tags: javascript

i'm using plain javascript to change an img tag `src` attribute like this:

```
let headerImage = document.getElementById('header-img');
headerImage.setAttribute('src', `./img/${newSrc}.png`);
headerImage.style.left = `calc(50vw - ${headerImage.naturalWidth / 2}px)`;
```

Now, the third line of this script won't wait for the second one to be done, making this piece of code: `headerImage.naturalWidth` useless for me.

So, is there a way to wait for the `setAttribute()` to be done in order to execute the last line of the script?

Thanks in advance.

**PD:** There's is a question here in stackoverflow that encourages the usage of `setTimeout()` to make it work but it works sometimes only.

Comment: `setTimeout()` would be the **wrong** way to do it. You can attach an event handler to the image object. The "load" event will fire when the image has loaded.

Comment: @Pointy This is way i said it, it does not work. And your method works just fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will fire a "load" event after the image has been loaded. (Also you don't need to use `.setAttribute()`; you can just set the "src" property.)

```
let headerImage = document.getElementById('header-img');
headerImage.onload = function() {
    headerImage.style.left = `calc(50vw - ${headerImage.naturalWidth / 2}px)`;
};
headerImage.src = `./img/${newSrc}.png`;
```